# Choosing Design Pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I am writing a component to parse data collected from various devices. Basic purpose and set of commands that these devices operate are same, the difference is the size and formatting of the data. So planning to write three parsers but the component should support dynamic support for other devices also. For example

```
interface IPayloadParser
{
    public void ParsePayload1(byte[] payload);
    public void ParsePayload2(byte[] payload);
    ...
    ...
    public void ParsePayloadn(byte[] payload);

}
```

is the contract that the parsers will implement. Selection of the parser is based on the type of device so thinking of using Factory Pattern to create the Parser and to implement the parsers, I am thinking of using Strategy pattern. Is this the right choice or should I use Template pattern here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Strategy pattern is a good fit.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

The key factor is the requirement to choose the implementation at runtime based on the device, which you have.